# Error setting class attribute with pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having an issue setting class attributes with a pointer, here is what my code looks like: (this version will compiles, but you need the have minesweeper window open).

```
WindowObject.h:

#ifndef WINDOWOBJECT_H_INCLUDED
#define WINDOWOBJECT_H_INCLUDED

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class WindowObject
{
public:
    WindowObject();

    BYTE* getPixelMap() const;
    void setPixelMap(BYTE* bitPointer);
    void getPixelMap(HWND hwnd);
private:
    BYTE* mPixelMap;
};

#endif
```

WindowObject.cpp:

```
#include "WindowObject.h"

WindowObject::WindowObject()
{
}

BYTE* WindowObject::getPixelMap() const
{
    printf("getPixelMap: %d\n", mPixelMap[0]); // it crashes, bad pointer!!
    return mPixelMap;
}

void WindowObject::setPixelMap(BYTE *bitPointer)
{
    printf("setPixelMap 1: %d\n", bitPointer[0]); // It works!
    mPixelMap = bitPointer;
    printf("setPixelMap 2: %d\n", mPixelMap [0]); // Why does this works and getPixelMap doesn't???
}

void WindowObject::getPixelMap(HWND hwnd)
{   
    HDC hdcWindow, hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    BITMAP bmpScreen;

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window.
    hdcWindow = GetDC(hwnd);

    // Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

    if(!hdcMemDC)
    {
        MessageBoxA(hwnd, "CreateCompatibleDC has failed", "Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Get the client area for size calculation
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top);

    if(!hbmScreen)
    {
        MessageBoxA(hwnd, "CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed", "Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    //Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP
    GetObject(hbmScreen,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmpScreen);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;    
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;
    BYTE* bitPointer;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;    
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;  
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    // Create a device independent bitmap that so that we can write to it directly
    hbmScreen = CreateDIBSection(hdcMemDC, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)(&bitPointer), NULL, NULL);

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.
    if ( !BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 0, 0, rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) )
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, "BitBlt has failed", "Failed", MB_OK);
        goto done;
    }

    // Create PixelMap
    int width = (rcClient.right-rcClient.left),
        height = (rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top);

    printf("Inside getPixelMap: %d\n", bitPointer[0]); // it works!
    setPixelMap(bitPointer);

done:
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdcWindow);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "WindowObject.h"

int main()
{
    WindowObject wObj;
    HWND hwnd;

    hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Minesweeper");

    if (hwnd)
    {
        wObj.getPixelMap(hwnd);
        BYTE* bPointer = wObj.getPixelMap();
        printf("After getPixelMap: %d", bPointer[0]);
    }
}
```

The program crashes, and it gives me an "access violation reading location". I'm almost 100% sure the problem comes from my pointer but I find it wierd that it works in every stage of my tests, except when I get it with my getPixelMap method. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't compile. `bitPointer` isn't in the scope of that member function.

Comment: I only gave the important part of my code, not everything is included which is why it won't compiles, should I post everything? I was scared it would be too much.

Comment: No, don't post everything. Post an [SSCCE](sscce.org).

Comment: And explain what "The program crashes" means.  What's the symptom of the crash?

Comment: Access violation reading location

Comment: I do not so much know windows-gui stuff. Nonetheless, it looks like `DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);` releases your bitmap memory. This happens right after you called `setPixelMap(bitPointer);` in the section labelled with `done`. Comment out the `done` stuff just for diagnosis and run your program. Does it still segfault? (It will leak memory. But you can accept that for the diagnosis phase.) Maybe, in the final solution you should copy your bitmap to some memory you really own in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the function getPixelMap(HWND hwnd) you are calling DeleteObject on the returned bitmap, after saving the pointer but before returning. So by the time you access the bitmap later, it is no longer a valid pointer, since according to the [CreateDIBSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs it says that the bitmap will be deallocated when you call DeleteObject.

You will need to keep the bitmap object (hbmScreen) and delete it later, perhaps in the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this data member either is not initialized (if an object of the class is default initialized) or has value 0. So using member function getPixelMap()  is unsafe. Also as I think the life of an argument of function setPixelMap may be less than the life of an object of the class. So the behaviour of the program is undefined.

I think it would be better to use either a smart pointer or to allocate a memory for using by the data member yourself.